# executar uma função quando for clicado no botao

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando fazer que só mande para o banco de dados quando clicar no botão porem toda vez que a pagina e carregada ele envia mesmo não clicando no botão.  Esse e o código q estou usando

```
<script>
 var text = "foi clicado"
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = "<?php 
        include 'conect.php';
        $ts = "<script>document.write(text)</script>";
        $TS2= $ts;
        $sql ="INSERT INTO `ss`(`nome`) VALUES ('$TS2')";
        $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        ?>";
}
</script>
```

se tiver como fazer conexão com o banco de dados via javascript e seja seguro fico feliz em saber tambem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível executar códigos php no lado do cliente, vocẽ deve usar AJAX para isso:

No JavaScript (JQuery):

```
$('#input').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        //Para aonde vai a requisição (um outro arquivo)
        url: 'arquivo_php.php',
        //Os dados que devem ser passados (adicione um id ao input e coloque no lugar de #input)
        data: {ts: $('#input').val()},
        //Como vai ser passados os dados (o mesmo method do form)
        method: 'POST',
    }).done(function(data) {
        //Quando finalizar a requisição com sucesso
        alert('Concluído com êxito');
    }).fail(function(error) {
        //Quando finalizar a requisição com falha
        alert('Erro: ' + error);
    });
});
```

No php (arquivo_php.php):

```
<?php 
    include 'conect.php';
    //Dado passado por post pelo ajax
    $TS2= $POST["ts"];
    $sql ="INSERT INTO `ss`(`nome`) VALUES ('$TS2')";
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

**Observação:** a tag `<button>` por padrão é do tipo `submit`, ou seja, ao ser clicada dentro de um formulário a página vai ser submetida, para que isso não ocorra defina o seu tipo como botão

```
<button type="button">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: obrigado ajudou muito